# replace exact string match with regexp in R

Tags: regex, r, replace, gsub

I have a vector of strings that need cleaning.
I have been able to clean it quite a lot on my own but I am having problems one thing.

Some strings have the chain '@56;' at the beginning (numbers vary). So a string can be '@56;trousers' or '@897;trousers'
I would like to leave it just like 'trousers'.

I have written the following code:

```
gsub("[@[:digit:];]", "", 'mystring')
```

but it fails in cases like:

```
gsub("[@[:digit:];]", "", '@34skirt') # returns 'skirt'
```

I would like it to return '@34skirt' in this case because the ; is missing from the end.

I want a exact match. Any ideas about how to do this? 
I ahve tried to add \ and it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[@[:digit:];]` regex matches a single character that is either a `@`, or a digit, or a `;`. Thus, it will remove those at any position in the string, as many times as it finds them with `gsub`.

You may use a regex defining a *sequence* of characters to remove, not a character class:

```
@[0-9]+;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jG9gD0/2)

You can even tell the regex engine to only remove those at the beginning of the string only:

```
^@[0-9]+;
```

[Sample demo](https://ideone.com/dDeoyE):

```
sub("^@[0-9]+;", "", '@34skirt')     ## [1] "@34skirt"
sub("^@[0-9]+;", "", '@34;trousers') ## [1] "trousers"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
sub("@\\d+;", "", v1)
#[1] "mystring" "@34skirt" "trousers" "trousers"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('mystring', '@34skirt',  '@56;trousers', '@897;trousers')
```